# Problem while adding new API to runtime, RPC, and service

Tags: runtime, rpc, service

```rs
pub fn create_full<C, P>(
    deps: FullDeps<C, P>,
) -> Result<RpcExtension, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>
where
    C: ProvideRuntimeApi<Block>
        + HeaderBackend<Block>
        + AuxStore
        + HeaderMetadata<Block, Error = BlockChainError>
        + Send
        + Sync
        + 'static,
    C::Api: pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::TransactionPaymentRuntimeApi<Block, Balance>,
    C::Api: substrate_frame_rpc_system::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Nonce>,
    C::Api: pallet_contracts_rpc::ContractsRuntimeApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash>,
    C::Api: BlockBuilder<Block>,
    P: TransactionPool + Sync + Send + 'static,
{
    use pallet_contracts_rpc::{Contracts, ContractsApiServer};
    use pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::{TransactionPayment, TransactionPaymentApiServer};
    use substrate_frame_rpc_system::{System, SystemApiServer};

    let mut module = RpcExtension::new(());
    let FullDeps { client, pool, deny_unsafe } = deps;

    module.merge(System::new(client.clone(), pool, deny_unsafe).into_rpc())?;
    module.merge(TransactionPayment::new(client.clone()).into_rpc())?;
    module.merge(Contracts::new(client).into_rpc())?;

    Ok(module)
}
```

I inserted a constraint to the standard rpc.rs create_full function:

```
C::Api: pallet_contracts_rpc::ContractsRuntimeApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash>,
```

I got an error:

```
C::Api: pallet_contracts_rpc::ContractsRuntimeApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash>,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `create_full`
```

```
 -> Result<Box<dyn ParachainConsensus<Block>>, sc_service::Error>, <RuntimeApi as ConstructRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_service::client::client::Client<sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, LocalCallExecutor<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, NativeElseWasmExecutor<Executor>>, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, RuntimeApi>>>::RuntimeApi: ContractsRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sp_runtime::AccountId32, u128, u32, H256>
```

Any suggestion what should I do is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `C` doesn't implement this trait.

Check the `C`, the `create_fuill<C, P>`'s `C`.

---

After taking a look at your code.

I think you missed the trait bound here https://github.com/hgminerva/humidefi-parachain/blob/015d477ee6a73479760d4ea072ce871e970a0d43/node/src/service.rs#L86-L93.

pseudo-code:

```rs
RuntimeApi::RuntimeApi: ContractApi
```

---

Made a PR to your repo https://github.com/hgminerva/humidefi-parachain/pull/1.

Comment: Sorry for being so novice, any hint will help on how to check C, all seems to match existing code in contract nodes, etc.

Comment: Without the full code, I can't do any further diagnosis.

Maybe you missed https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0e33b4e9a3deb0a3637f0c618c6c8ac24f36c0d2/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1951-L2021.

Comment: in my runtime i am using this: ```impl pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash>```

Comment: I posted the code above.

Comment: You should add something like this to your `new_partial`. https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/d17ee12922b069423b0d9eb562d579eaebe0940e/node/service/src/lib.rs#L391-L392

Comment: in my new_partial I already have the following: ``` RuntimeApi::RuntimeApi: sp_transaction_pool::runtime_api::TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>
 + sp_api::Metadata<Block>
 + sp_session::SessionKeys<Block>
 + sp_api::ApiExt<
  Block,
  StateBackend = sc_client_api::StateBackendFor<TFullBackend<Block>, Block>,```

Comment: By the way, I am using the parachain-template to add a pallet_contracts

Comment: Obviously, you didn't specify the contract API in the `RuntimeApi`. IMHO, you'd better learn some Rust first.

Comment: Sorry, so how can you specify.  As far as my little knowledge would show, you just need to implement it in ```impl_runtime_apis!``` and I already did ```impl pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash>```

Comment: Also I added ```impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime``` in the runtime.  Unless I miss something.

Comment: Sorry being so forceful :) , you can check the implementation here: https://github.com/hgminerva/humidefi-parachain/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L510

Comment: Add the api here. https://github.com/hgminerva/humidefi-parachain/blob/015d477ee6a73479760d4ea072ce871e970a0d43/node/src/service.rs#L86-L93

Comment: It doesn't work.  I tried adding RuntimeApi::RuntimeApi: ContractsApi

Comment: No, you don't. Check https://github.com/hgminerva/humidefi-parachain/pull/1.

Still recommending you learn some Rust first. I have already given the answer to you and you said you have tried that...

Comment: OMG....I was modifying the new_partial function, ....much love  , it worked!   thanks so much, you are a heaven sent.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer.